# Transfer function with blackbox modelling is too slow compared to real expectation

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, step-response

I collected this data from a robot that drives with its wheels up. The blue curve is the voltage and that is my input. The orange curve is the wheel velocity and that is my output.

[image]

I want to create a transfer function for when the voltage changes from 1 volt to 2 volt, and I don't want to include the part where the robot slows down. So I cut off the data so I only look the interval [1.05 , 2] sec. I also offset these values so they both start at 0.

[image]

Now I try to estimate a transfer function for this response, with `tfest(data, 1, 0)`  and I get $H(s) = \frac{0.3916}{s+1.202}$, which is fine I guess. However, when I plot the step response the system with this transfer function I get this.

[image]

As you can see it takes much longer time for the output to reach 0.3 m/s than in the experiment. It takes about 4 seconds for the step response to reach 0.3m/s, but in the experiment it only took 0.2 seconds.

Why is my transfer function so slow to reach the actual output value? Does it have something to do with the way I cropped the data?

### Edit

Here is my MATLAB code:

```
close all
clear
data = load('Emilie_day4_1.txt');

% Emilie (25)
%  1    time 0.004 sec
%  2  3 Motor voltage [V] left, right: 0.00 0.00
%  4  5 Wheel velocity [m/s] left, right: -0.0000 -0.0000
figure(100)
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2))
hold on
plot(data(:,1), data(:,4))
grid on
legend('Left voltage' , 'Left Velocity')
xlabel('time (sec)')
hold off

figure(100)
plot(data(350:end-50,1), data(350:end-50,2)-1)
hold on
plot(data(350:end-50,1), data(350:end-50,4)-0.25)
grid on
legend('Left voltage' , 'Left Velocity')
xlabel('time (sec)')
hold off

ddin = (data(350:end-50,2)-1);
ddout = (data(350:end-50,4)-0.25);
idd1 = iddata(ddout, ddin, 0.05);



sys1 = tfest(idd1, 1, 0)

step(sys1)
```

The data is just collected in a simple text-file, but I couldn't post the text file in here so I just copied and pasted the numbers:

```
%% logfile from robot Emilie (25)
% Emilie (25)

%  1    time 0.001 sec

%  2  3 Motor voltage [V] left, right: 0.00 0.00

%  4  5 Wheel velocity [m/s] left, right: 0.0000 0.0000

0.001 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.004 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.007 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.010 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.013 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.016 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.019 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.022 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.025 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.028 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.031 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.034 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.037 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.040 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.043 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.046 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.049 0.00 0.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.052 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.055 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.058 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.061 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.064 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0000 

0.067 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.0908 

0.070 1.00 1.00 0.0000 0.1229 

0.073 1.00 1.00 0.0397 0.1249 

0.076 1.00 1.00 0.0397 0.1504 

0.079 1.00 1.00 0.0574 0.1414 

0.082 1.00 1.00 0.0574 0.1498 

0.085 1.00 1.00 0.0689 0.1454 

0.088 1.00 1.00 0.0689 0.1747 

0.091 1.00 1.00 0.0817 0.1895 

0.094 1.00 1.00 0.1061 0.1748 

0.097 1.00 1.00 0.1262 0.1963 

0.100 1.00 1.00 0.1375 0.1963 

0.103 1.00 1.00 0.1442 0.2174 

0.106 1.00 1.00 0.1438 0.2187 

0.109 1.00 1.00 0.1573 0.2107 

0.112 1.00 1.00 0.1663 0.2128 

0.115 1.00 1.00 0.1513 0.2157 

0.118 1.00 1.00 0.1735 0.2439 

0.121 1.00 1.00 0.1840 0.2413 

0.124 1.00 1.00 0.1753 0.2621 

0.127 1.00 1.00 0.1847 0.2442 

0.130 1.00 1.00 0.1775 0.2279 

0.133 1.00 1.00 0.1710 0.2491 

0.136 1.00 1.00 0.1911 0.2390 

0.139 1.00 1.00 0.1961 0.2496 

0.142 1.00 1.00 0.1888 0.2448 

0.145 1.00 1.00 0.2004 0.2216 

0.148 1.00 1.00 0.1871 0.2796 

0.151 1.00 1.00 0.1874 0.2379 

0.154 1.00 1.00 0.2008 0.2463 

0.157 1.00 1.00 0.1973 0.2600 

0.160 1.00 1.00 0.1940 0.2540 

0.164 1.00 1.00 0.1951 0.2668 

0.167 1.00 1.00 0.2033 0.2471 

0.170 1.00 1.00 0.2143 0.2635 

0.173 1.00 1.00 0.2105 0.2455 

0.176 1.00 1.00 0.2183 0.2758 

0.179 1.00 1.00 0.2037 0.2520 

0.182 1.00 1.00 0.2057 0.2772 

0.185 1.00 1.00 0.2245 0.2991 

0.188 1.00 1.00 0.2177 0.2787 

0.191 1.00 1.00 0.2128 0.2950 

0.194 1.00 1.00 0.2048 0.2840 

0.197 1.00 1.00 0.1997 0.3047 

0.200 1.00 1.00 0.2197 0.2818 

0.203 1.00 1.00 0.2167 0.3006 

0.206 1.00 1.00 0.2127 0.2839 

0.209 1.00 1.00 0.2376 0.3096 

0.212 1.00 1.00 0.1997 0.2849 

0.215 1.00 1.00 0.2321 0.2769 

0.218 1.00 1.00 0.2245 0.3037 

0.221 1.00 1.00 0.2352 0.2593 

0.224 1.00 1.00 0.2252 0.2652 

0.227 1.00 1.00 0.2292 0.2788 

0.230 1.00 1.00 0.2391 0.2696 

0.233 1.00 1.00 0.2198 0.2829 

0.236 1.00 1.00 0.2407 0.2636 

0.239 1.00 1.00 0.2154 0.2830 

0.242 1.00 1.00 0.2359 0.3138 

0.245 1.00 1.00 0.2197 0.2894 

0.248 1.00 1.00 0.2224 0.3059 

0.251 1.00 1.00 0.2226 0.2915 

0.254 1.00 1.00 0.2169 0.3127 

0.257 1.00 1.00 0.2383 0.2907 

0.260 1.00 1.00 0.2305 0.2910 

0.263 1.00 1.00 0.2417 0.2826 

0.266 1.00 1.00 0.2213 0.2645 

0.269 1.00 1.00 0.2285 0.2668 

0.272 1.00 1.00 0.2370 0.2852 

0.275 1.00 1.00 0.2330 0.2695 

0.278 1.00 1.00 0.2401 0.2794 

0.281 1.00 1.00 0.2153 0.2733 

0.284 1.00 1.00 0.2344 0.2465 

0.287 1.00 1.00 0.2308 0.3151 

0.290 1.00 1.00 0.2237 0.2876 

0.293 1.00 1.00 0.2501 0.3079 

0.296 1.00 1.00 0.2223 0.2894 

0.299 1.00 1.00 0.2415 0.3145 

0.302 1.00 1.00 0.2321 0.2893 

0.305 1.00 1.00 0.2425 0.2862 

0.308 1.00 1.00 0.2321 0.2627 

0.311 1.00 1.00 0.2352 0.2956 

0.314 1.00 1.00 0.2441 0.2679 

0.317 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.2975 

0.320 1.00 1.00 0.2431 0.2758 

0.323 1.00 1.00 0.2172 0.2927 

0.326 1.00 1.00 0.2376 0.3086 

0.329 1.00 1.00 0.2205 0.2960 

0.332 1.00 1.00 0.2236 0.3158 

0.335 1.00 1.00 0.2228 0.2928 

0.338 1.00 1.00 0.2284 0.3109 

0.341 1.00 1.00 0.2383 0.2925 

0.344 1.00 1.00 0.2301 0.2837 

0.347 1.00 1.00 0.2328 0.2774 

0.350 1.00 1.00 0.2134 0.2498 

0.353 1.00 1.00 0.2213 0.3078 

0.356 1.00 1.00 0.2308 0.2575 

0.359 1.00 1.00 0.2269 0.2652 

0.362 1.00 1.00 0.2377 0.2778 

0.365 1.00 1.00 0.2206 0.3117 

0.368 1.00 1.00 0.2407 0.2857 

0.371 1.00 1.00 0.2368 0.3054 

0.374 1.00 1.00 0.2294 0.2908 

0.377 1.00 1.00 0.2562 0.3133 

0.380 1.00 1.00 0.2131 0.2895 

0.383 1.00 1.00 0.2511 0.3067 

0.386 1.00 1.00 0.2299 0.2738 

0.389 1.00 1.00 0.2409 0.2777 

0.392 1.00 1.00 0.2199 0.2647 

0.395 1.00 1.00 0.2337 0.2802 

0.398 1.00 1.00 0.2432 0.2883 

0.401 1.00 1.00 0.2234 0.2711 

0.404 1.00 1.00 0.2271 0.3129 

0.407 1.00 1.00 0.2175 0.2945 

0.410 1.00 1.00 0.2372 0.3200 

0.413 1.00 1.00 0.2273 0.2948 

0.416 1.00 1.00 0.2241 0.3121 

0.419 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.2987 

0.422 1.00 1.00 0.2301 0.2653 

0.425 1.00 1.00 0.2347 0.2726 

0.428 1.00 1.00 0.2328 0.2853 

0.431 1.00 1.00 0.2451 0.2755 

0.434 1.00 1.00 0.2271 0.2881 

0.437 1.00 1.00 0.2462 0.2692 

0.440 1.00 1.00 0.2405 0.2865 

0.443 1.00 1.00 0.2376 0.3098 

0.446 1.00 1.00 0.2295 0.2859 

0.449 1.00 1.00 0.2363 0.3028 

0.452 1.00 1.00 0.2424 0.2884 

0.455 1.00 1.00 0.2300 0.3099 

0.458 1.00 1.00 0.2410 0.2893 

0.461 1.00 1.00 0.2229 0.2883 

0.464 1.00 1.00 0.2096 0.2850 

0.467 1.00 1.00 0.2487 0.2675 

0.470 1.00 1.00 0.2200 0.2688 

0.473 1.00 1.00 0.2336 0.2883 

0.476 1.00 1.00 0.2228 0.2722 

0.479 1.00 1.00 0.2464 0.2839 

0.482 1.00 1.00 0.2343 0.3106 

0.485 1.00 1.00 0.2457 0.2991 

0.488 1.00 1.00 0.2293 0.3208 

0.491 1.00 1.00 0.2273 0.2938 

0.494 1.00 1.00 0.2241 0.3126 

0.497 1.00 1.00 0.2304 0.2937 

0.500 1.00 1.00 0.2408 0.2892 

0.503 1.00 1.00 0.2216 0.2700 

0.506 1.00 1.00 0.2423 0.2886 

0.509 1.00 1.00 0.2374 0.2661 

0.512 1.00 1.00 0.2416 0.2985 

0.515 1.00 1.00 0.2256 0.3036 

0.518 1.00 1.00 0.2325 0.2890 

0.521 1.00 1.00 0.2451 0.3103 

0.524 1.00 1.00 0.2373 0.2896 

0.527 1.00 1.00 0.2440 0.3060 

0.530 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.2934 

0.533 1.00 1.00 0.2430 0.3114 

0.536 1.00 1.00 0.2386 0.2866 

0.539 1.00 1.00 0.2269 0.2885 

0.542 1.00 1.00 0.2510 0.2719 

0.545 1.00 1.00 0.2165 0.2828 

0.548 1.00 1.00 0.2430 0.2751 

0.551 1.00 1.00 0.2331 0.2492 

0.554 1.00 1.00 0.2446 0.3092 

0.557 1.00 1.00 0.2251 0.2908 

0.560 1.00 1.00 0.2380 0.3106 

0.563 1.00 1.00 0.2467 0.2918 

0.566 1.00 1.00 0.2268 0.3170 

0.569 1.00 1.00 0.2309 0.2913 

0.572 1.00 1.00 0.2204 0.3098 

0.575 1.00 1.00 0.2401 0.2785 

0.578 1.00 1.00 0.2295 0.2969 

0.581 1.00 1.00 0.2260 0.2701 

0.584 1.00 1.00 0.2264 0.2996 

0.587 1.00 1.00 0.2317 0.2778 

0.591 1.00 1.00 0.2360 0.2950 

0.594 1.00 1.00 0.2409 0.3108 

0.597 1.00 1.00 0.2251 0.2924 

0.600 1.00 1.00 0.2273 0.2713 

0.603 1.00 1.00 0.2466 0.2740 

0.606 1.00 1.00 0.2370 0.2915 

0.609 1.00 1.00 0.2446 0.2747 

0.612 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.2852 

0.615 1.00 1.00 0.2372 0.3111 

0.618 1.00 1.00 0.2383 0.2986 

0.621 1.00 1.00 0.2308 0.3203 

0.624 1.00 1.00 0.2584 0.2930 

0.627 1.00 1.00 0.2296 0.3127 

0.630 1.00 1.00 0.2488 0.2937 

0.633 1.00 1.00 0.2382 0.2833 

0.636 1.00 1.00 0.2491 0.2640 

0.639 1.00 1.00 0.2277 0.2829 

0.642 1.00 1.00 0.2420 0.2611 

0.645 1.00 1.00 0.2503 0.2932 

0.648 1.00 1.00 0.2294 0.2664 

0.651 1.00 1.00 0.2274 0.2963 

0.654 1.00 1.00 0.2167 0.3135 

0.657 1.00 1.00 0.2369 0.2915 

0.660 1.00 1.00 0.2268 0.3078 

0.663 1.00 1.00 0.2234 0.2952 

0.666 1.00 1.00 0.2234 0.3151 

0.669 1.00 1.00 0.2297 0.2917 

0.672 1.00 1.00 0.2346 0.2886 

0.675 1.00 1.00 0.2321 0.2732 

0.678 1.00 1.00 0.2446 0.2832 

0.681 1.00 1.00 0.2278 0.2770 

0.684 1.00 1.00 0.2487 0.2498 

0.687 1.00 1.00 0.2435 0.3118 

0.690 1.00 1.00 0.2420 0.2928 

0.693 1.00 1.00 0.2324 0.3118 

0.696 1.00 1.00 0.2395 0.2926 

0.699 1.00 1.00 0.2407 0.3187 

0.702 1.00 1.00 0.2381 0.2935 

0.705 1.00 1.00 0.2510 0.3116 

0.708 1.00 1.00 0.2313 0.2741 

0.711 1.00 1.00 0.2513 0.2977 

0.714 1.00 1.00 0.2397 0.2708 

0.717 1.00 1.00 0.2264 0.3010 

0.720 1.00 1.00 0.2346 0.2780 

0.723 1.00 1.00 0.2384 0.2959 

0.726 1.00 1.00 0.2478 0.3117 

0.729 1.00 1.00 0.2355 0.2984 

0.732 1.00 1.00 0.2477 0.3182 

0.735 1.00 1.00 0.2202 0.2948 

0.738 1.00 1.00 0.2398 0.3135 

0.741 1.00 1.00 0.2235 0.2750 

0.744 1.00 1.00 0.2263 0.2857 

0.747 1.00 1.00 0.2259 0.2783 

0.750 1.00 1.00 0.2204 0.2503 

0.753 1.00 1.00 0.2414 0.3113 

0.756 1.00 1.00 0.2340 0.2612 

0.759 1.00 1.00 0.2455 0.3073 

0.762 1.00 1.00 0.2277 0.2887 

0.765 1.00 1.00 0.2329 0.3137 

0.768 1.00 1.00 0.2424 0.2886 

0.771 1.00 1.00 0.2398 0.3066 

0.774 1.00 1.00 0.2304 0.2923 

0.777 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.3145 

0.780 1.00 1.00 0.2433 0.2762 

0.783 1.00 1.00 0.2361 0.2977 

0.786 1.00 1.00 0.2497 0.2755 

0.789 1.00 1.00 0.2304 0.2787 

0.792 1.00 1.00 0.2163 0.2650 

0.795 1.00 1.00 0.2562 0.2809 

0.798 1.00 1.00 0.2257 0.3175 

0.801 1.00 1.00 0.2399 0.2948 

0.804 1.00 1.00 0.2293 0.3149 

0.807 1.00 1.00 0.2529 0.2965 

0.810 1.00 1.00 0.2400 0.3218 

0.813 1.00 1.00 0.2521 0.2918 

0.816 1.00 1.00 0.2248 0.2529 

0.819 1.00 1.00 0.2324 0.3147 

0.822 1.00 1.00 0.2271 0.2673 

0.825 1.00 1.00 0.2295 0.2746 

0.828 1.00 1.00 0.2301 0.2876 

0.831 1.00 1.00 0.2240 0.3205 

0.834 1.00 1.00 0.2449 0.2934 

0.837 1.00 1.00 0.2366 0.3129 

0.840 1.00 1.00 0.2486 0.2973 

0.843 1.00 1.00 0.2283 0.3174 

0.846 1.00 1.00 0.2349 0.2853 

0.849 1.00 1.00 0.2441 0.2925 

0.852 1.00 1.00 0.2419 0.2717 

0.855 1.00 1.00 0.2315 0.2743 

0.858 1.00 1.00 0.2257 0.2620 

0.861 1.00 1.00 0.2445 0.2770 

0.864 1.00 1.00 0.2369 0.2857 

0.867 1.00 1.00 0.2501 0.2682 

0.871 1.00 1.00 0.2307 0.3120 

0.874 1.00 1.00 0.2502 0.2949 

0.877 1.00 1.00 0.2397 0.2878 

0.880 1.00 1.00 0.2481 0.2798 

0.883 1.00 1.00 0.2370 0.2530 

0.886 1.00 1.00 0.2416 0.3145 

0.889 1.00 1.00 0.2502 0.2677 

0.892 1.00 1.00 0.2299 0.3145 

0.895 1.00 1.00 0.2345 0.2952 

0.898 1.00 1.00 0.2236 0.3205 

0.901 1.00 1.00 0.2431 0.2943 

0.904 1.00 1.00 0.2320 0.3036 

0.907 1.00 1.00 0.2293 0.2895 

0.910 1.00 1.00 0.2291 0.2917 

0.913 1.00 1.00 0.2349 0.2645 

0.916 1.00 1.00 0.2393 0.2947 

0.919 1.00 1.00 0.2366 0.2741 

0.922 1.00 1.00 0.2489 0.2761 

0.925 1.00 1.00 0.2306 0.2636 

0.928 1.00 1.00 0.2495 0.2788 

0.931 1.00 1.00 0.2401 0.3141 

0.934 1.00 1.00 0.2423 0.2910 

0.937 1.00 1.00 0.2328 0.3103 

0.940 1.00 1.00 0.2391 0.2930 

0.943 1.00 1.00 0.2405 0.3189 

0.946 1.00 1.00 0.2332 0.2939 

0.949 1.00 1.00 0.2511 0.2702 

0.952 1.00 1.00 0.2324 0.3121 

0.955 1.00 1.00 0.2526 0.2657 

0.958 1.00 1.00 0.2419 0.2725 

0.961 1.00 1.00 0.2534 0.2874 

0.964 1.00 1.00 0.2415 0.2767 

0.967 1.00 1.00 0.2452 0.2940 

0.970 1.00 1.00 0.2536 0.3127 

0.973 1.00 1.00 0.2332 0.2978 

0.976 1.00 1.00 0.2363 0.3199 

0.979 1.00 1.00 0.2236 0.2952 

0.982 1.00 1.00 0.2424 0.3018 

0.985 1.00 1.00 0.2319 0.2792 

0.988 1.00 1.00 0.2422 0.2816 

0.991 1.00 1.00 0.2284 0.2642 

0.994 1.00 1.00 0.2346 0.2791 

0.997 1.00 1.00 0.2393 0.2871 

1.000 1.00 1.00 0.2452 0.2874 

1.003 1.00 1.00 0.2413 0.3057 

1.006 1.00 1.00 0.2319 0.2880 

1.009 1.00 1.00 0.2510 0.3136 

1.012 1.00 1.00 0.2424 0.2885 

1.015 1.00 1.00 0.2510 0.3051 

1.018 1.00 1.00 0.2354 0.2941 

1.021 1.00 1.00 0.2422 0.2751 

1.024 1.00 1.00 0.2426 0.2691 

1.027 1.00 1.00 0.2350 0.2822 

1.030 1.00 1.00 0.2632 0.2731 

1.033 1.00 1.00 0.2297 0.2878 

1.036 1.00 1.00 0.2535 0.2684 

1.039 1.00 1.00 0.2353 0.2884 

1.042 1.00 1.00 0.2448 0.3196 

1.045 1.00 1.00 0.2245 0.2955 

1.048 1.00 1.00 0.2386 0.3121 

1.051 1.00 1.00 0.2478 0.2965 

1.054 2.00 2.00 0.2293 0.3143 

1.057 2.00 2.00 0.2516 0.2898 

1.060 2.00 2.00 0.2757 0.3272 

1.063 2.00 2.00 0.2849 0.3839 

1.066 2.00 2.00 0.3042 0.3549 

1.069 2.00 2.00 0.3231 0.4066 

1.072 2.00 2.00 0.3523 0.4087 

1.075 2.00 2.00 0.3621 0.4636 

1.078 2.00 2.00 0.3630 0.4676 

1.081 2.00 2.00 0.3909 0.4542 

1.084 2.00 2.00 0.4140 0.4737 

1.087 2.00 2.00 0.4162 0.4757 

1.090 2.00 2.00 0.4087 0.4932 

1.093 2.00 2.00 0.4577 0.5175 

1.096 2.00 2.00 0.4504 0.5372 

1.099 2.00 2.00 0.4106 0.5051 

1.102 2.00 2.00 0.4644 0.5224 

1.105 2.00 2.00 0.4487 0.5082 

1.109 2.00 2.00 0.4709 0.5515 

1.112 2.00 2.00 0.4636 0.5599 

1.115 2.00 2.00 0.4666 0.5718 

1.118 2.00 2.00 0.4799 0.5362 

1.121 2.00 2.00 0.4752 0.5390 

1.124 2.00 2.00 0.5014 0.5386 

1.127 2.00 2.00 0.5001 0.6373 

1.131 2.00 2.00 0.4996 0.6026 

1.134 2.00 2.00 0.5035 0.6069 

1.137 2.00 2.00 0.5089 0.5909 

1.140 2.00 2.00 0.4959 0.5704 

1.143 2.00 2.00 0.5338 0.6637 

1.146 2.00 2.00 0.5158 0.6623 

1.149 2.00 2.00 0.4965 0.5639 

1.152 2.00 2.00 0.5194 0.6177 

1.155 2.00 2.00 0.5280 0.6263 

1.158 2.00 2.00 0.5082 0.5601 

1.161 2.00 2.00 0.5355 0.5763 

1.164 2.00 2.00 0.5304 0.6717 

1.167 2.00 2.00 0.5357 0.6070 

1.170 2.00 2.00 0.5880 0.5838 

1.173 2.00 2.00 0.5691 0.6339 

1.176 2.00 2.00 0.5479 0.6030 

1.179 2.00 2.00 0.5642 0.6874 

1.182 2.00 2.00 0.5465 0.6917 

1.185 2.00 2.00 0.5378 0.6354 

1.188 2.00 2.00 0.5355 0.6504 

1.191 2.00 2.00 0.5445 0.6041 

1.194 2.00 2.00 0.5423 0.6959 

1.197 2.00 2.00 0.5481 0.6968 

1.200 2.00 2.00 0.5444 0.6076 

1.203 2.00 2.00 0.5413 0.6570 

1.206 2.00 2.00 0.5139 0.6219 

1.209 2.00 2.00 0.5253 0.7094 

1.212 2.00 2.00 0.5792 0.6432 

1.215 2.00 2.00 0.5288 0.6444 

1.218 2.00 2.00 0.5595 0.6562 

1.221 2.00 2.00 0.5804 0.5991 

1.224 2.00 2.00 0.5846 0.6884 

1.227 2.00 2.00 0.5808 0.6301 

1.230 2.00 2.00 0.5813 0.6558 

1.233 2.00 2.00 0.5826 0.6540 

1.236 2.00 2.00 0.5548 0.6209 

1.239 2.00 2.00 0.6101 0.7041 

1.242 2.00 2.00 0.5892 0.6479 

1.245 2.00 2.00 0.5673 0.6582 

1.248 2.00 2.00 0.5821 0.5861 

1.251 2.00 2.00 0.5500 0.7047 

1.254 2.00 2.00 0.5530 0.6325 

1.257 2.00 2.00 0.5504 0.6421 

1.260 2.00 2.00 0.5564 0.6674 

1.263 2.00 2.00 0.5681 0.6137 

1.266 2.00 2.00 0.5749 0.7109 

1.269 2.00 2.00 0.5885 0.6008 

1.272 2.00 2.00 0.5492 0.6658 

1.275 2.00 2.00 0.5944 0.6148 

1.278 2.00 2.00 0.5966 0.7146 

1.281 2.00 2.00 0.6011 0.6755 

1.284 2.00 2.00 0.5871 0.6505 

1.288 2.00 2.00 0.5568 0.6991 

1.291 2.00 2.00 0.5541 0.6584 

1.294 2.00 2.00 0.5749 0.6584 

1.297 2.00 2.00 0.5651 0.6876 

1.300 2.00 2.00 0.5667 0.7106 

1.303 2.00 2.00 0.5861 0.6928 

1.306 2.00 2.00 0.5916 0.6581 

1.309 2.00 2.00 0.5913 0.6701 

1.312 2.00 2.00 0.5959 0.6240 

1.315 2.00 2.00 0.5986 0.7142 

1.318 2.00 2.00 0.5665 0.6175 

1.321 2.00 2.00 0.5437 0.6711 

1.324 2.00 2.00 0.5640 0.6328 

1.327 2.00 2.00 0.5715 0.7126 

1.330 2.00 2.00 0.5614 0.6501 

1.333 2.00 2.00 0.5665 0.6568 

1.336 2.00 2.00 0.5616 0.5812 

1.339 2.00 2.00 0.5541 0.7039 

1.342 2.00 2.00 0.5274 0.6828 

1.345 2.00 2.00 0.5266 0.6405 

1.348 2.00 2.00 0.5720 0.6657 

1.351 2.00 2.00 0.5301 0.6129 

1.354 2.00 2.00 0.5938 0.7110 

1.357 2.00 2.00 0.5940 0.6009 

1.360 2.00 2.00 0.5928 0.6671 

1.364 2.00 2.00 0.5596 0.7059 

1.367 2.00 2.00 0.5613 0.6778 

1.370 2.00 2.00 0.5577 0.6711 

1.373 2.00 2.00 0.5513 0.6084 

1.376 2.00 2.00 0.5234 0.7187 

1.379 2.00 2.00 0.5350 0.6761 

1.382 2.00 2.00 0.6017 0.6708 

1.385 2.00 2.00 0.5971 0.6970 

1.388 2.00 2.00 0.5887 0.7228 

1.391 2.00 2.00 0.5840 0.6568 

1.394 2.00 2.00 0.5851 0.6669 

1.397 2.00 2.00 0.5405 0.6160 

1.400 2.00 2.00 0.5664 0.7002 

1.403 2.00 2.00 0.5624 0.6373 

1.406 2.00 2.00 0.5741 0.6635 

1.409 2.00 2.00 0.5610 0.6610 

1.412 2.00 2.00 0.5630 0.6260 

1.415 2.00 2.00 0.5584 0.7143 

1.418 2.00 2.00 0.5468 0.6544 

1.421 2.00 2.00 0.5847 0.6662 

1.424 2.00 2.00 0.5579 0.5906 

1.427 2.00 2.00 0.5795 0.7140 

1.430 2.00 2.00 0.5922 0.6411 

1.434 2.00 2.00 0.5694 0.7168 

1.437 2.00 2.00 0.5571 0.6998 

1.440 2.00 2.00 0.5583 0.6515 

1.443 2.00 2.00 0.5574 0.6808 

1.446 2.00 2.00 0.5598 0.6153 

1.449 2.00 2.00 0.5909 0.7078 

1.452 2.00 2.00 0.5470 0.6501 

1.455 2.00 2.00 0.5778 0.6619 

1.458 2.00 2.00 0.5970 0.6164 

1.461 2.00 2.00 0.5961 0.7057 

1.464 2.00 2.00 0.5960 0.6123 

1.467 2.00 2.00 0.5974 0.6660 

1.470 2.00 2.00 0.5673 0.6679 

1.473 2.00 2.00 0.5742 0.6982 

1.476 2.00 2.00 0.6237 0.7223 

1.479 2.00 2.00 0.5647 0.6604 

1.482 2.00 2.00 0.5544 0.6732 

1.485 2.00 2.00 0.5557 0.6238 

1.488 2.00 2.00 0.5510 0.7142 

1.491 2.00 2.00 0.5540 0.6522 

1.494 2.00 2.00 0.5818 0.6760 

1.497 2.00 2.00 0.5820 0.6182 

1.500 2.00 2.00 0.5710 0.7168 

1.503 2.00 2.00 0.5960 0.6000 

1.506 2.00 2.00 0.5965 0.6682 

1.509 2.00 2.00 0.6013 0.6106 

1.512 2.00 2.00 0.6040 0.7150 

1.515 2.00 2.00 0.5792 0.6926 

1.518 2.00 2.00 0.5953 0.6714 

1.521 2.00 2.00 0.5609 0.6479 

1.524 2.00 2.00 0.5640 0.7129 

1.527 2.00 2.00 0.5614 0.6487 

1.530 2.00 2.00 0.5895 0.6795 

1.533 2.00 2.00 0.5751 0.6628 

1.536 2.00 2.00 0.5828 0.6205 

1.539 2.00 2.00 0.5943 0.7020 

1.542 2.00 2.00 0.5976 0.6825 

1.545 2.00 2.00 0.5968 0.6732 

1.548 2.00 2.00 0.6012 0.6104 

1.551 2.00 2.00 0.5904 0.7189 

1.554 2.00 2.00 0.5704 0.6761 

1.557 2.00 2.00 0.5461 0.6743 

1.560 2.00 2.00 0.5583 0.7013 

1.563 2.00 2.00 0.5605 0.7250 

1.566 2.00 2.00 0.5612 0.6600 

1.569 2.00 2.00 0.5667 0.6726 

1.572 2.00 2.00 0.5947 0.6217 

1.575 2.00 2.00 0.5557 0.7156 

1.578 2.00 2.00 0.5287 0.6514 

1.581 2.00 2.00 0.6010 0.6753 

1.584 2.00 2.00 0.6067 0.6203 

1.587 2.00 2.00 0.6085 0.7090 

1.590 2.00 2.00 0.5487 0.6034 

1.593 2.00 2.00 0.5704 0.6674 

1.596 2.00 2.00 0.5740 0.6147 

1.599 2.00 2.00 0.5636 0.7141 

1.602 2.00 2.00 0.5686 0.6891 

1.605 2.00 2.00 0.5642 0.6689 

1.608 2.00 2.00 0.5572 0.6457 

1.611 2.00 2.00 0.5303 0.7191 

1.614 2.00 2.00 0.5408 0.6689 

1.617 2.00 2.00 0.6085 0.5744 

1.620 2.00 2.00 0.6088 0.6686 

1.623 2.00 2.00 0.6046 0.6010 

1.626 2.00 2.00 0.5738 0.6960 

1.629 2.00 2.00 0.5775 0.6636 

1.632 2.00 2.00 0.5554 0.6585 

1.635 2.00 2.00 0.5713 0.6003 

1.638 2.00 2.00 0.5695 0.6391 

1.641 2.00 2.00 0.5688 0.7159 

1.644 2.00 2.00 0.5346 0.6484 

1.647 2.00 2.00 0.5470 0.6732 

1.650 2.00 2.00 0.5998 0.6213 

1.653 2.00 2.00 0.6094 0.7195 

1.656 2.00 2.00 0.6059 0.6596 

1.659 2.00 2.00 0.6055 0.6560 

1.662 2.00 2.00 0.5733 0.6121 

1.665 2.00 2.00 0.5559 0.7014 

1.668 2.00 2.00 0.5814 0.6353 

1.671 2.00 2.00 0.5676 0.6637 

1.674 2.00 2.00 0.5694 0.6635 

1.677 2.00 2.00 0.5672 0.6924 

1.680 2.00 2.00 0.5429 0.7144 

1.683 2.00 2.00 0.6010 0.6521 

1.687 2.00 2.00 0.5761 0.5899 

1.690 2.00 2.00 0.5529 0.6909 

1.693 2.00 2.00 0.5620 0.6376 

1.696 2.00 2.00 0.5688 0.6730 

1.699 2.00 2.00 0.5673 0.6231 

1.702 2.00 2.00 0.5785 0.7220 

1.705 2.00 2.00 0.5956 0.5753 

1.708 2.00 2.00 0.5556 0.6613 

1.711 2.00 2.00 0.5990 0.6157 

1.714 2.00 2.00 0.6022 0.7167 

1.717 2.00 2.00 0.6049 0.6775 

1.720 2.00 2.00 0.5927 0.6669 

1.723 2.00 2.00 0.5506 0.6042 

1.726 2.00 2.00 0.5737 0.7110 

1.729 2.00 2.00 0.5794 0.6635 

1.732 2.00 2.00 0.5702 0.6689 

1.735 2.00 2.00 0.5742 0.6960 

1.738 2.00 2.00 0.6039 0.6219 

1.741 2.00 2.00 0.5636 0.7241 

1.744 2.00 2.00 0.5358 0.6628 

1.747 2.00 2.00 0.6091 0.6723 

1.750 2.00 2.00 0.6152 0.6247 

1.753 2.00 2.00 0.6116 0.7149 

1.756 2.00 2.00 0.5485 0.6219 

1.759 2.00 2.00 0.5713 0.6723 

1.762 2.00 2.00 0.5753 0.6353 

1.765 2.00 2.00 0.5645 0.7194 

1.768 2.00 2.00 0.5703 0.6566 

1.771 2.00 2.00 0.5664 0.6671 

1.774 2.00 2.00 0.5584 0.5943 

1.777 2.00 2.00 0.5317 0.7157 

1.780 2.00 2.00 0.5424 0.6404 

1.783 2.00 2.00 0.6111 0.6750 

1.786 2.00 2.00 0.6086 0.6248 

1.789 2.00 2.00 0.6061 0.7233 

1.792 2.00 2.00 0.5731 0.5782 

1.795 2.00 2.00 0.5775 0.6727 

1.798 2.00 2.00 0.5566 0.6226 

1.801 2.00 2.00 0.5708 0.7199 

1.804 2.00 2.00 0.5676 0.6838 

1.807 2.00 2.00 0.5698 0.6780 

1.810 2.00 2.00 0.5333 0.6132 

1.813 2.00 2.00 0.5421 0.7230 

1.816 2.00 2.00 0.6121 0.6809 

1.819 2.00 2.00 0.6086 0.6781 

1.822 2.00 2.00 0.6088 0.7065 

1.825 2.00 2.00 0.5742 0.7293 

1.828 2.00 2.00 0.5801 0.6638 

1.831 2.00 2.00 0.5569 0.6798 

1.834 2.00 2.00 0.5684 0.6262 

1.837 2.00 2.00 0.5628 0.7221 

1.840 2.00 2.00 0.5645 0.6566 

1.843 2.00 2.00 0.5476 0.6813 

1.846 2.00 2.00 0.5411 0.6232 

1.849 2.00 2.00 0.5978 0.7232 

1.852 2.00 2.00 0.6063 0.6139 

1.855 2.00 2.00 0.6056 0.6765 

1.858 2.00 2.00 0.6042 0.6212 

1.861 2.00 2.00 0.6029 0.7270 

1.864 2.00 2.00 0.5560 0.6997 

1.867 2.00 2.00 0.5806 0.6804 

1.870 2.00 2.00 0.5791 0.6442 

1.873 2.00 2.00 0.5736 0.7152 

1.876 2.00 2.00 0.5717 0.6463 

1.879 2.00 2.00 0.5473 0.6708 

1.882 2.00 2.00 0.6091 0.6385 

1.885 2.00 2.00 0.5585 0.7302 

1.889 2.00 2.00 0.5572 0.6821 

1.892 2.00 2.00 0.5690 0.6292 

1.895 2.00 2.00 0.5740 0.7076 

1.898 2.00 2.00 0.5669 0.6580 

1.901 2.00 2.00 0.5835 0.6742 

1.904 2.00 2.00 0.6000 0.6144 

1.907 2.00 2.00 0.5599 0.7120 

1.910 2.00 2.00 0.6051 0.6060 

1.913 2.00 2.00 0.6064 0.6695 

1.916 2.00 2.00 0.6118 0.6161 

1.920 2.00 2.00 0.5642 0.6738 

1.923 2.00 2.00 0.5669 0.6268 

1.926 2.00 2.00 0.5930 0.7168 

1.929 2.00 2.00 0.5934 0.6222 

1.932 2.00 2.00 0.6079 0.6747 

1.935 2.00 2.00 0.6083 0.6395 

1.938 2.00 2.00 0.6080 0.7273 

1.941 2.00 2.00 0.6365 0.6669 

1.944 2.00 2.00 0.6122 0.6757 

1.947 2.00 2.00 0.5706 0.6008 

1.950 2.00 2.00 0.5711 0.7236 

1.953 2.00 2.00 0.5679 0.6458 

1.956 2.00 2.00 0.5713 0.6822 

1.959 2.00 2.00 0.6018 0.6313 

1.963 2.00 2.00 0.5602 0.6792 

1.966 2.00 2.00 0.5852 0.6839 

1.969 2.00 2.00 0.5728 0.7309 

1.972 2.00 2.00 0.5722 0.6685 

1.975 2.00 2.00 0.5717 0.6825 

1.978 2.00 2.00 0.5458 0.6258 

1.981 2.00 2.00 0.6008 0.7233 

1.984 2.00 2.00 0.6077 0.6581 

1.987 2.00 2.00 0.6058 0.6804 

1.990 2.00 2.00 0.6054 0.6226 

1.993 2.00 2.00 0.5923 0.7212 

1.996 2.00 2.00 0.5560 0.6096 

1.999 2.00 2.00 0.5834 0.6757 

2.002 2.00 2.00 0.5731 0.6192 

2.005 2.00 2.00 0.5793 0.7237 

2.008 2.00 2.00 0.5742 0.6983 

2.011 2.00 2.00 0.5486 0.6779 

2.014 2.00 2.00 0.6115 0.6543 

2.017 2.00 2.00 0.6143 0.7290 

2.020 2.00 2.00 0.6115 0.6500 

2.023 2.00 2.00 0.6122 0.6829 

2.026 2.00 2.00 0.5843 0.6303 

2.029 2.00 2.00 0.5632 0.7281 

2.032 2.00 2.00 0.5786 0.6691 

2.035 2.00 2.00 0.5708 0.6807 

2.038 2.00 2.00 0.5686 0.6316 

2.041 2.00 2.00 0.5540 0.7232 

2.044 2.00 2.00 0.5433 0.6280 

2.047 2.00 2.00 0.6024 0.6786 

2.050 2.00 2.00 0.6177 0.6428 

2.053 2.00 2.00 0.6196 0.7314 

2.056 0.00 0.00 0.6113 0.6595 

2.059 0.00 0.00 0.5379 0.6287 

2.062 0.00 0.00 0.5355 0.5808 

2.065 0.00 0.00 0.4798 0.5422 

2.068 0.00 0.00 0.4367 0.5014 

2.071 0.00 0.00 0.3905 0.4519 

2.074 0.00 0.00 0.3753 0.4089 

2.077 0.00 0.00 0.3650 0.4216 

2.080 0.00 0.00 0.3180 0.3699 

2.083 0.00 0.00 0.3158 0.3248 

2.086 0.00 0.00 0.2689 0.2849 

2.089 0.00 0.00 0.2724 0.2777 

2.092 0.00 0.00 0.2246 0.2455 

2.095 0.00 0.00 0.2184 0.1980 

2.098 0.00 0.00 0.2048 0.2246 

2.101 0.00 0.00 0.1747 0.2179 

2.104 0.00 0.00 0.1755 0.1671
```

After changing the sample time to 0.03 I get this step response.

[image]

Comment: How did you create `data`? I'm asking because it looks like `tfest` doesn't get the correct information concerning the sampling instants.

Comment: @MattL. I edited the question adding my code and my data, which was contained in a text file. Unfortunately I can't post the file here, so I just copied and pasted the numbers.

Comment: It looks like your sampling interval is $0.003$, but you specify `Ts=0.05` in your call to  `iddata`. That would explain the time stretch in the step response.

Comment: @MattL. Thank you! Yeah that really did reduce the time for it to reach the actual value. However, it still takes the step response 1s to reach 0.3m/s, is there anything I can do to make the fit better, or is that the best I can do, do you think?

Comment: @MattL. By the way, if you want to make an answer with your comment I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: Ok, good idea. Note that $T_s$ needs to be $0.003$ instead of $0.03$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original code you defined the sampling interval to be $T_s=0.05$ (`idd1 = iddata(ddout, ddin, 0.05);`). Yet, according to the data file, the time step between sample points appears to be $T_s=0.003$. Changing $T_s$ from $0.5$ to $0.003$ should compress the step response by a factor of $0.05/0.003=16.67$, which compares favorably to the relation between the actual rise time and the one predicted by the model (with the wrong $T_s$).

In your updated model you seem to have changed the sampling interval to $T_s=0.03$, which is still a factor $10$ too large (unless there's a typo in the sentence above the last figure). Note that you need to specify $T_s=0.003$.